# How can i Edit manifest in GUI mode

Tags: android, intellij-plugin, intellij-13

I am trying to edit my manifest in intellij13 but i could not switch to GUI mode like in ADT we can use the GUI or we can directly code the xml.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you confusing the difference between the manifest and layout files?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice,Thank you for the reply...Nope,ahh i.c i mean same as the ADT that we can generate xml through like GUI,not manually coded the xml.